# How can I remove everything after a specific text present in html ? Using python and beautifulsoup4

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape wikipedia. I wish to get only the desired data and discard everthing which is unncessary such as **See also**, **References**, etc.

```
<h2>
     <span class="mw-headline" id="See_also">See also</span>
</h2>
<ul>
     <li><a href="/wiki/List_of_adaptations_of_works_by_Stephen_King" title="List of adaptations of works by Stephen King">List of adaptations of works by Stephen King</a></li>
     <li><a href="/wiki/Castle_Rock_(Stephen_King)" title="Castle Rock (Stephen King)">Castle Rock (Stephen King)</a></li>
     <li><a href="/wiki/Charles_Scribner%27s_Sons" title="Charles Scribner&#39;s Sons">Charles Scribner's Sons</a> (aka Scribner)</li>
     <li><a href="/wiki/Derry_(Stephen_King)" title="Derry (Stephen King)">Derry (Stephen King)</a></li>
     <li><a href="/wiki/Dollar_Baby" title="Dollar Baby">Dollar Baby</a></li>
     <li><a href="/wiki/Jerusalem%27s_Lot_(Stephen_King)" title="Jerusalem&#39;s Lot (Stephen King)">Jerusalem's Lot (Stephen King)</a></li>
     <li><i><a href="/wiki/Haven_(TV_series)" title="Haven (TV series)">Haven</a></i></li>
</ul>
```

As shown in the above HTML. If I find **See also** in **h2** tag, I want to delete everything which is followed by it. unordered list in this case.

Comment: it would be simpler get it as text, find position and slice it with `html = html[:position]`

Comment: with `beautifulsoup` or `lxml` you can use `extract()` to remove element so it would need to remove them one by one

Comment: maybe you should use better method to get only desired data instead of removing other data.

Comment: The suggestion for using position logic is good, but it is not effficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use CSS selector with `~` to select right elements to extract:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

txt = '''
<div>This I want to keep</div>
<h2>
     <span class="mw-headline" id="See_also">See also</span>
</h2>
<ul>
     <li><a href="/wiki/List_of_adaptations_of_works_by_Stephen_King" title="List of adaptations of works by Stephen King">List of adaptations of works by Stephen King</a></li>
     <li><a href="/wiki/Castle_Rock_(Stephen_King)" title="Castle Rock (Stephen King)">Castle Rock (Stephen King)</a></li>
     <li><a href="/wiki/Charles_Scribner%27s_Sons" title="Charles Scribner&#39;s Sons">Charles Scribner's Sons</a> (aka Scribner)</li>
     <li><a href="/wiki/Derry_(Stephen_King)" title="Derry (Stephen King)">Derry (Stephen King)</a></li>
     <li><a href="/wiki/Dollar_Baby" title="Dollar Baby">Dollar Baby</a></li>
     <li><a href="/wiki/Jerusalem%27s_Lot_(Stephen_King)" title="Jerusalem&#39;s Lot (Stephen King)">Jerusalem's Lot (Stephen King)</a></li>
     <li><i><a href="/wiki/Haven_(TV_series)" title="Haven (TV series)">Haven</a></i></li>
</ul>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(txt, 'html.parser')

for tag in soup.select('h2:contains("See also") ~ *, h2:contains("See also")'):
    tag.extract()

print(soup)
```

Prints:

```html
<div>This I want to keep</div>
```

---

NOTE: Newer versions of `bs4` use `:-soup-contains` instead of `:contains`

Comment: This works. Can you explain what exactly ```for tag in soup.select('h2:contains("See also") ~ *, h2:contains("See also")'):``` does?

Comment: @HemantSirsat `h2:contains("See also") ~ *` is CSS selector that selects all tags which are that preceded by a `<h2>` element containing "See also".